# Python cannot find my imported llama index python packages

Tags: python, llama-index

Summary:

Python cannot find my imported llama index python packages.

It's clear that my llama index packages are already installed successfully, but those packages are located in a slightly different file path, than the file path that python searches with 'import' command.

As a result, python cannot find my imported llama index python packages everytime.

Code: ###

running ls show gives the following file path for llama index package.

```
pip3 show llama-index-readers-wikipedia
Name: llama-index-readers-wikipedia
Version: 0.1.3
Summary: llama-index readers wikipedia integration
Home-page:
Author: Your Name
Author-email: you@example.com
License: MIT
Location: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages
Requires: llama-index-core
Required-by:
```

so its clear that the file has been installed in the computer it looks like.

running the from and import commands, I get this ::

```
python3 from llama_index.readers.wikipedia import WikipediaReader
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file '/Users/nicholaske/Downloads/from': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

So we can see it says the file is not there, but of course, you can also see the file path is a different one. Could this be the reason why it's not working???

--
(Explanation)
I am very new to python and the coding world in general.. however I am having a lot of issues with llama index installation (and/or moving files).

I have installed llama index core and that seems fine, and I was able to install python.

I am trying to install various packages from llama index into python.

Now the issue is that -

For instance

Installation

pip3 install llama-index-readers-wikipedia

This installs fine (its installed in a python site-packages which seems to be the correct file path.

However when I run
python3 from llama_index.readers.wikipeadia import WikipediaReader

It is saying that the file is no where near to be found.

The file path here is /Resources/Python.app/Contents.. etc.

The sub folder that python3 searches every time is in a different location than the sub folder for the site directory.

My question is, is it normal for both to be sorted in slightly different sub folders?? If so, then how will the command for python3 from _**file package name** work ?? It is always trying to find it in a different file location then where the file (package) was originally installed...

Using the from and import command, I have the same issue across all my python packages. I installed them fine, but running the from and import command, python is looking for the files in a different location then where they are installed every time.

Since I am very new I am not sure. However

Given my installation stack, know that I use pip3 and python3 every time (pip and python don't work, probs because I have installed python3 in my mac, and the (3) is used to indicate the new version).

I have tried this with several other python packages so I know it's the same problem.

The import and from functions , given that they are python specific functions, seem to work when I add python3 in front, which shows to my mac terminal that the code must be interpreted from python3 (when I don't write python3 it will not recognize the import and from commands, so I know the issue isn't the import and from commands, it's something to do with the location of the files it seems. )

Comment: Don't make us guess what exact command you used to run the code, and don't make us guess what the actual error message was.  Please edit your question and include the exact command, and the exact error traceback message.

Comment: Are you literally running the terminal command `python3 from llama_index.readers.wikipeadia import WikipediaReader`? Short scripts are usually run like `python3 -c "print('hello')"` (note the quotes). What's the exact error message you're getting? Also you have a typo: it's `wikipedia`, not `wikipeadia`

Comment: thank you for the comments everyone !! I have edited the question with a 'code' section, it shows the exact error message(s) for the commands that have been used.

Comment: You're running python the wrong way.  You're supposed to put your python code in a file, named something like `myscript.py`, and then run `python myscript.py`.  (You can run short bits of code directly from the command line, as @ForceBru commented, but it doesn't seem like that's what you intended to do here.)

Comment: thank you for the quick reply! how would I put it all in a file ;) ?? pls see if you can redirect me to another thread to have a look... 

for the llama index package, would I have to access this exact file and then maybe I run it as from llama_index.readers.wikipedia.py ?

Comment: _how would I put it all in a file_ Umm... with a text editor?  I don't understand what you are asking.  Do you really not know how to create a file?

Comment: "I am very new to python and the coding world in general" - please study at least the first three chapters of [the official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) before jumping straight to LLMs